# Permission denied error while crawling when using tab-completion with roslaunch

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, ros

I am using ROS Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04.

Using `roslaunch` returns the following error as soon as I press <kbd>tab</kbd>:

```
roslaunch [rospack] Warning: error while crawling /home/user: boost::filesystem::status: Permission denied: "/home/user/.gvfs
```

I should mention while building my packages, `youbot_driver_ros_interface` asked for root password. Building was successful, however when I type `roslaunch` <kbd>tab</kbd>, that error message appears.

Comment: When building requires a root password, there is something wrong in the first place (this should usually not happen). Do you have write permission for your workspace (including build and devel directories)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, I think you have a broken mount that you need to un-mount to fix your error. The following might fix your problem:

> umount /home/user/.gvfs

Or you may just reboot your machine :)

Comment: you were right! I had an iso mounted, i unmount it and restarted and it works fine! Thanks!